# SCALA: How to convert a Parser Combinator result to Scala List[String]?

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I am trying to write a parser for a language very similar to Milner's CCS. Basically what I am parsing so far are expressions of the following sort:

- a.b.a.1
- a.0

An expression must start with a letter (excluding t) and could have any number of letters following the first letter (separated by a '.'). The Expression must terminate with a digit (for simplicity I chose digits between 0 and 2 for now). I want to use Parser Combinators for Scala, however this is the first time that I am working with them. This is what I have so far:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class SimpleParser extends RegexParsers {
  def alpha: Parser[String] = """[^t]{1}""".r ^^ { _.toString }
  def digit: Parser[Int] = """[0-2]{1}""".r ^^ { _.toInt }

  def expr: Parser[Any] = alpha ~ "." ~ digit ^^ {
    case al ~ "." ~ di => List(al, di)
  }

  def simpleExpression: Parser[Any] = alpha ~ "." ~ rep(alpha ~ ".") ~ digit //^^ {  }
}
```

As you can see in `def expr :Parser[Any]` I am trying to return the result as a list, since Lists in Scala are very easy to work with (in my opinion). Is this the correct way how to convert a Parser[Any] result to a List? Can anyone give me any tips on how I can do this for `def simpleExpression:Parser[Any]`.

The main reason why I want to use Lists is because after parsing and Expression I want to be able to consume it. For example, given the expression **a.b.1**, if I am given an *'a'*, I would like to consume the expression to end up with a new expression: **b.1** (i.e. **a.b.1 ->(a)-> b.1**). The idea behind this is to simulate finite state automatas. Any tips on how I may improve my implementation are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keeps things type safe, I recommend a parser that produces a tuple of a list of strings and an int. That is, the input `a.b.a.1` would get parsed as `(List("a", "b", "a"), 1)`. Note also that the regex for alpha was modified to exclude anything that is not a lowercase letter (in addition to t).

```
class SimpleParser extends RegexParsers {
  def alpha: Parser[String] = """[a-su-z]{1}""".r ^^ { _.toString }
  def digit: Parser[Int] = """[0-2]{1}""".r ^^ { _.toInt }

  def repAlpha: Parser[List[String]] = rep1sep(alpha, ".")

  def expr: Parser[(List[String], Int)] = repAlpha ~ "." ~ digit ^^ {
    case alphas ~ _ ~ num =>
      (alphas, num)
  }
}
```

With an instance of this `SimpleParser`, here's the output I got:

```
println(parser.parse(parser.expr, "a.b.a.1"))
// [1.8] parsed: (List(a, b, a),1)

println(parser.parse(parser.expr, "a.0"))
// [1.4] parsed: (List(a),0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How would you go about pattern matching the list in the tuple then? Is it just like normal pattern matching with lists?

Comment: I managed. What I did was the following: 
```def consume(c: String, t: (List[String],Int)):(List[String],Int)= {
    t._1 match {
      case Nil => (List(),t._2)
      case x::xs => if (x.equalsIgnoreCase(c)) (xs,t._2)
                    else (x::xs,t._2)
    }
  }```